# How to find in flask application if the content is from cache

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a flask application and set the cache timeout to 150 seconds. Is there a flag or an option to differentiate if the content is fresh or from cache

```
@app.route("/info")
@cache.cached(timeout=150)
def infopage():
    rows = fetch_data()
    return render_template("info.tmpl", rows=rows)
```